# compare custom value in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to compare grade in pandas but the grade is not number. I want to keep the highest grade in the new column[keep] and other duplicate code will write something in the new column[keep].
The grade rule is Gold>Sliver>Bronze

example csv:

```
VIP_CODE|Grade
123|Gold
321|Sliver
123|Gold
321|Bronze
456|Sliver
456|Gold
```

Expect result:

```
VIP_CODE|Grade|keep
123|Gold|yes
321|Sliver|yes
123|Gold|yes
321|Bronze|dup by 321
456|Sliver|dup by 456
456|Gold|yes
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'VIP_CODE': {0: 123, 1: 321, 2: 123, 3: 321, 4: 456, 5: 456},
    'Grade': {0: 'Gold', 1: 'Silver', 2: 'Gold', 3: 'Bronze',
              4: 'Silver', 5: 'Gold'}
})

# Assign Numerical Value To Each Grade
df['weight'] = df['Grade'].map({'Gold': 2, 'Silver': 1, 'Bronze': 0})
# Get Max For Each Group
df['max'] = df.groupby('VIP_CODE')['weight'].transform('max')
# Where weight is max for group
df['keep'] = np.where(
    df['max'] == df['weight'],
    'yes',
    'dup by ' + df['VIP_CODE'].astype(str)
)

# Drop extra columns
df = df.drop(columns=['weight', 'max'])

# For Display
print(df.to_csv(sep='|', index=False))
```

`df`:

```
VIP_CODE|Grade|keep
123|Gold|yes
321|Silver|yes
123|Gold|yes
321|Bronze|dup by 321
456|Silver|dup by 456
456|Gold|yes
```